# How to get the another field if the expected value choose from dropdown in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get another field like interview date field if selected appointed interview from dropdown field,
[image]

Here is my view ,

```
   <form action="{{ route('jobseekers.updatestatus', $jobseekers->id) }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title"> Choose Status:</label>
                                <?php $status = \App\Status::all(); ?>
                                <select id="val_select" name="status" class="form-control select2">
                                    <option value="{{ $jobseekers->status }}">{{ $jobseekers->mystatus['description'] }}</option>
                                    @foreach($status as $row)
                                        <option value="{{ $row->id }}">
                                            {{ $row->description }} 
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>


      <div class="form-group"> 
           <form action="{{ route('jobseekers.updatestatus', $jobseekers->id) }}">
                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                   {{ method_field("patch") }}
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Status</button>
   </form>
```

So like,if i select Appointed Interview, I want to be another appointed date field appear automatically,otherwise not appear the appointed date field.Is there anyway to do like that?

Comment: Use jquery on change event to show hide appointed date after changing Appointed Interview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery change event on your select box.

First, make your desired field hidden

```
<form action="{{ route('jobseekers.updatestatus', $jobseekers->id) }}" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field("patch") }}

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title"> Choose Status:</label>
      <?php $status = \App\Status::all(); ?>
      <select id="val_select" name="status" class="form-control select2">
          <option value="{{ $jobseekers->status }}">{{ $jobseekers->mystatus['description'] }}</option>
          @foreach($status as $row)
              <option value="{{ $row->id }}">
                  {{ $row->description }} 
              </option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group hide" id="date-input">
      <label for="title"> Date:</label>
      <input name="date" />         
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">            
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Status</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

After that, add a jquery change event listener to your select box

```
$(function () {
    $('select[name="status"]').change(function () {
        //remove the hide class from date-input
        if ($(this).find(":selected").val() == 'appointed-interview') {
            $('#date-input').removeClass('hide')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: hi,bro thanks for the detail explaination, but i actually want the extra date field is only when we select the appointed interview, if select another option like second time recommended something like that..., i dun want to show the extra date, any idea bro?

Comment: @ThanHtutOo Updated my answer.